What is the meaning of "I've been bound up lately."?
What is the meaning of "I've been bound up lately."?
Is that related to the constipation or to the fact that he has been involved in lots of stuff.  I have not found in the dictionaries the meaning of bound up with regard to the constipation except for the "Bound-up bowels", which means constipation. Is that what he is referring to?
It is from the movie, 'Uncle Buck', and the following is the context.
Buck:
Do you have a plunger?  While I'm thinking of these things. For the morning.
My plumbing is bad. Of course, yours is good.
I would imagine. Don't worry about it.
Everything will be fine.

I've been bound up lately.

It's driving me crazy. I've been eating a lot of cheese for some reason.                
I got a craving for the stuff.
Do you think maybe that's an allergy?

Thank you.

Bound up = tied up = not moving (the alimentary canal; constipated). See eggbound.

@FumbleFingers - plenty of times I've been egg-bound. A beastly smell, believe me! Drop an eggy one etc.

@MichaelHarvey: I think that one relates to hydrogen sulfide being the smell of rotten eggs. My link relates to constipation (I think primarily caused by lack of dietary fibre, but I dunno) in a diet high in eggs.

@FumbleFingers - sorry, I combined, in one comment, being egg-bound (constipated by eating too many eggs) and dropping an eggy one (breaking wind while 9in that condition).

Thank you FumbleFingers, MichaelHarvey for the answer and comments.
